# Concatenate in Goggle sheet if NOT Blank

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have this formula in Google sheets

Basically, I want to concatenate only if Both Cells W2 and AA2 are NOT BLANK.

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(W2)),NOT(ISBLANK(AA2))),CONCATENATE(H2,"-",AA2),"")
```

It Concatenate me the cells because i guess W2 and AA2 have some Array formulas.

Is there a workaround this ?

Comment: What happens when your run your query?

Comment: Please share a sample sheet, if possible.  I don't find any errors using CONCATENATE when referencing cells with an ARRAYFORMULA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=IF((W2<>"")*(AA2<>""), H2&"-"&AA2, )
```

for AF use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((W2:W<>"")*(AA2:AA<>""), H2:H2&"-"&AA2:AA, ))
```